What can I do to make my mint more minty and way less bitter?
My mint just came back up and is already coarse and bitter. How can I make it less so?

What kind of mint do you have? And - I hope that mint is in a pot and not running rampant through your garden.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you steep mint for half a minute and compost it, your tea, soup stock, or tomato sauce will be bright and not bitter.

Might be the variety (there are thousands, which tend to get lumped into a much smaller number, so the "peppermint" from one suplier and the "peppermint" from another supplier may not be the same, albeit similar. Might be the way you are using it - please [edit] to describe how you use it, including which parts of the plant (young leaves, old leaves, stems, blosoms, etc.) and how you extract flavor from it.

I grow Bowles (apple) mint, which keeps a good flavour in the leaves even when they're big and coarse.  What do you grow?
